# Can anyone give me an example of where Depth-First Search cannot find a solution on a finite graph

Tags: artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I have been asked the above question by a lecturer at University, I have done some research and asked the question prior with no help. I really need help with this, I counts towards my final grade, can someone please explain an example to me. I cannot understand how something that is finite could never find the solution as eventually it would travel other paths to find its goal.

If it was infinite then I can understand it will keep traveling down, never actually reaching its goal.

Please help me, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

If the graph has cycles, then a depth first search could get stuck in a cycle before finding the desired element.

Answer (score 1):

Wit this search algorithm it is possible to get caught in infinite paths; this occurs when the graph is infinite or when there are cycles in the graph; or
solutions exist at shallow depth, because in this case the search may look at many long paths before finding the short solutions. In your case would be because there are cycles in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

If any node the graph has a self loop then it will get stuck in infinite loop.